# redirect to home after login using React react-router and usenavigate not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I want the user to be redirected to the home page after successfully logging in, I store the data of the api request to log in the user in a variable called currentUser, so if currentUser is true it should redirect to home.
this is how i handle the login request :

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")) || null
  );

  const login = async (inputs) => {

  

    const res= await axios.post("https://micacarballo-social-media-api.onrender.com/api/v1/auth/login",inputs,{
      
    })
  setCurrentUser(res.data)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
  }, [currentUser,login]);
 
  const updateUser = async () =>{
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    const res= await axios.get("https://micacarballo-social-media-api.onrender.com/api/v1/users/me/",{
 headers: {
  Authorization: `jwt ${user.token}`
 }

    })
   setCurrentUser(res.data)
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login , updateUser}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My protected routes :

```
import { AuthContext } from './context/authContext'
function App() {
  
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

 

  

 const Layout = ()=>{
  

  return(
    <div  >
        <Navbar  />
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <LeftBar />
          <div style={{ flex: 6 }}>
            <Outlet   />
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
  )
 }
 
 const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) =>{
  if(!currentUser){
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }return children
  
}


  const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
      path: "/",
      element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
      <Layout/>
      
      </ProtectedRoute>
      ),
      children :[
        {
          path:"/",
          element: <Home />
        },{
          path:"/profile/:id",
          element:<Profile />
        }
      ]
    }, {
      path: "/login",
      element: <Login />,
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      element: <Register />
    },
    
  ]);

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and my login page :

```
const Login = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [err, setErr] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // state variable for loading spinner


  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };
  const {login} = useContext(AuthContext)

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true); // set loading to true
      await login(inputs);
      navigate("/")
      
      
     
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(err.response.data);
    }finally {
      setIsLoading(false); // set loading back to false
    }
  };
       

    return (
      <div className='login'>
      <div className="card">
          <div className="left">
              <h1>SocialMica</h1>
              <p>
                  Make connecting with friends easy and fun
              </p>
              <span>Dont have an account yet?</span>
               <Link to="/register">
               <button>Register</button>
               </Link>
             
          </div>
          <div className="right">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <form action="">
                <input type="email" placeholder='email' name='email' onChange={handleChange}></input>
                <input type="password"placeholder='password' name='password' onChange={handleChange}/>
               {err && "invalid email or password"}
               
               <button onClick={handleLogin} disabled={isLoading}> {isLoading ? <Loading/> : "Login"}</button>
              
               
              </form>
              </div>

      </div>
  </div> )
}

export default Login
```

I dont understand why its not working, after the user is logged in and currentUser stores the data, the login page just refresh and doesnt redirect,I have to manually access to the home page.
I tried changing the navigate to ("/register) in the handleSubmit function in the login page and it works properly but not with navigate('/')

Answer (score 0):

change your path `/home` not only `/`
just like

```
{
    path:"/home",
    element: <Home />
},
```

it should working

Comment: Hi thank you! doesnt throw me any errors but it still doesnt solve the redirecting issue

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue is that in the `handleLogin` callback the `login` handler enqueues a `currentUser` state update and in the same render cycle enqueues a navigation action. When the navigation action is immediately processed the `currentUser` state is yet to be updated and the `AuthContextProvider` hasn't rerendered with the updated `currentUser` state for the UI to read. This means that `ProtectedRoute` reads the not-yet-updated `currentUser` state value and redirects back to `"/login"`. The reason redirecting to `"/register"` works is because it's not rendered on a protected route.

## Solution Suggestions

To get around this you need to update the code to not enqueue the state update and navigation request in the same render cycle.

- Method 1: delay the `navigate` call to the end of the Javascript event queue in the `handleLogin` handler.

  ```js
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true); // set loading to true

      await login(inputs);

      // Allow state update to process, then redirect
      setTimeout(navigate, 0, "/", { replace: true });
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(err.response.data);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false); // set loading back to false
    }
  };
  ```
- Method 2: delay the return of the `login` call to the end of the Javascript event queue

  ```js
  const login = async (inputs) => {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "https://micacarballo-social-media-api.onrender.com/api/v1/auth/login",
      inputs,
      {}
    );

    // Enqueue state update
    setCurrentUser(res.data);

    // Delay return so state can update first
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 0);
    })
  };
  ```

### Demo

[image: Edit strange-hoover-coi7hg]

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time! it seems like after i login, it redirects to the home '/'(i can see the url changing) but as you said it doesnt reflect in the UI, the only solution that worked was making the page refresh after navigating to home, not sure if that's the best way, like this: `const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true); // set loading to true
      await login(inputs);
      navigate('/')
      window.location.reload(true) 
    } '..`

Comment: @MicaCarballo You shouldn't need to manually reload the page for anything. Can you fork my sandbox and add more of your actual code that reproduces the rendering issue that you need to manually reload the page for that we could inspect live?