# React Router v6.10 AuthContext + createBrowserRouter - problem with navigate

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I am trying to create an app with protected routes in react using react router. I used the official example (https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/auth) to create the app.

The example works fine. It's using `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Route>` components etc... However, the documentation says about `createBrowserRouter`:
"This is the recommended router for all React Router web projects. It uses the DOM History API to update the URL and manage the history stack."

So I tried to implement the `createBrowserRouter` into the first example and there is the problem. When user tries to log in, `auth.signin()` store the value but the redirect to `/protected` works after second try. Does anyone can explain, why `navigate()` in `LoginPage` component not working for the first time? Or how to fix this?

Here is the updated code using `createBrowserRouter`

main.tsx

```
import './index.css';

import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {
    createBrowserRouter,
    Link,
    Navigate,
    Outlet,
    RouterProvider,
    useLocation,
    useNavigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { fakeAuthProvider } from './auth';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                element: <PublicPage />,
            },
            {
                path: '/login',
                element: <LoginPage />,
            },
            {
                path: '/protected',
                element: (
                    <RequireAuth>
                        <ProtectedPage />
                    </RequireAuth>
                ),
            },
        ],
    },
]);

export default function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <h1>Auth Example</h1>

            <p>
                This example demonstrates a simple login flow with three pages: a public page, a protected page, and a
                login page. In order to see the protected page, you must first login. Pretty standard stuff.
            </p>

            <p>
                First, visit the public page. Then, visit the protected page. You're not yet logged in, so you are
                redirected to the login page. After you login, you are redirected back to the protected page.
            </p>

            <p>
                Notice the URL change each time. If you click the back button at this point, would you expect to go back
                to the login page? No! You're already logged in. Try it out, and you'll see you go back to the page you
                visited just *before* logging in, the public page.
            </p>

            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

function Layout() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AuthStatus />

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Public Page</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
}

interface AuthContextType {
    user: any;
    signin: (user: string, callback: VoidFunction) => void;
    signout: (callback: VoidFunction) => void;
}

let AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);

function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    let [user, setUser] = React.useState<any>(null);

    let signin = (newUser: string, callback: VoidFunction) => {
        return fakeAuthProvider.signin(() => {
            setUser(newUser);
            callback();
        });
    };

    let signout = (callback: VoidFunction) => {
        return fakeAuthProvider.signout(() => {
            setUser(null);
            callback();
        });
    };

    let value = { user, signin, signout };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

function useAuth() {
    return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}

function AuthStatus() {
    let auth = useAuth();
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    if (!auth.user) {
        return <p>You are not logged in.</p>;
    }

    return (
        <p>
            Welcome {auth.user}!{' '}
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    auth.signout(() => navigate('/'));
                }}
            >
                Sign out
            </button>
        </p>
    );
}

function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
    let auth = useAuth();
    let location = useLocation();

    if (!auth.user) {
        // Redirect them to the /login page, but save the current location they were
        // trying to go to when they were redirected. This allows us to send them
        // along to that page after they login, which is a nicer user experience
        // than dropping them off on the home page.
        return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
    }

    return children;
}

function LoginPage() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let location = useLocation();
    let auth = useAuth();

    let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';

    function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        let username = formData.get('username') as string;

        auth.signin(username, () => {
            // Send them back to the page they tried to visit when they were
            // redirected to the login page. Use { replace: true } so we don't create
            // another entry in the history stack for the login page.  This means that
            // when they get to the protected page and click the back button, they
            // won't end up back on the login page, which is also really nice for the
            // user experience.
            navigate(from, { replace: true });
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You must log in to view the page at {from}</p>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Username: <input name="username" type="text" />
                </label>{' '}
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

function PublicPage() {
    return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
    return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}
```

The problem and what i tried is described in previous textarea

Comment: State update is enqueued in the same render cycle as the navigation action is effect. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75914850/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese Omg. Thank you very much! The change from `navigate(from, { replace: true });` to `setTimeout(navigate, 0, from, { replace: true });` was exactly what I need. You made my day.  Hope that this solution is not going against some best practice

Comment: It might borderline be considered a bit of a hack since ideally I think you'd want to set any state/etc *then* return a Promise to the UI to then effect a navigation action. With such simple code like what you have and what is in the other answer though, the "hack" gets you by. In my experience using redux state management I've not quite seen this synchronicity issue pop up.

Comment: Yes, redux is also one way to do this. Or there is still a working solution using BrowserRouter based on the default auth example.

Comment: Honestly it might've been an "issue" introduced in one of the later RRDv6 updates. The auth example hasn't been change AFAIK since v6 released, but the maintainers are active in version updates, making what I'd consider to be rather major changes (almost breaking changes I'd dare say).